# Cannot execute any MySQL query after COMMIT

Tags: php, mysql

I execute some MySQL queries using `START TRANSACTION`, but after I execute `COMMIT` the following queries do not take effect in the database

The following queries were executed using mysqli_query in the same order:

`SET names utf8`

`SET AUTOCOMMIT=0`

`START TRANSACTION`

`INSERT INTO table1 (a, b) VALUES (1,2) ;`

`INSERT INTO table2 (c, d) VALUES (1,1) ;`

`INSERT INTO table2 (c, d) VALUES (2,1) ;`

`COMMIT`

`INSERT INTO table3 (e, f) VALUES (9,7) ;` <-- This does not insert anything!!

**Note:** The last query should be executed out of the `START TRANSACTION` `COMMIT`block.

That is really driving me crazy. Because I cannot seem to figure out the problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0`, so I'll have to query `COMMIT` after each query.

So the solution is either to set the `SET AUTOCOMMIT=1` or to use `COMMIT` after each query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the order of the instructions. 
Try to execute commit at the end.

```
SET names utf8

SET AUTOCOMMIT=0

START TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO table1 (a, b) VALUES (1,2) ;

INSERT INTO table2 (c, d) VALUES (1,1) ;

INSERT INTO table2 (c, d) VALUES (2,1) ;

INSERT INTO table3 (e, f) VALUES (9,7) ;

COMMIT
```

Comment: The last query should be executed after `COMMIT` because it has to be executed whether I `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. Sorry that I didn't make that clear in the question.

Comment: To disable autocommit mode explicitly, use the following statement:

SET autocommit=0;
After disabling autocommit mode by setting the autocommit variable to zero, changes to transaction-safe tables (such as those for InnoDB, BDB, or NDBCLUSTER) are not made permanent immediately. You must use COMMIT to store your changes to disk or ROLLBACK to ignore the changes.